# How to place code from JsFiddle to a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code on JsFiddle and cannot seem to be able to place it into my website in HTML and JavaScript format. I placed the CSS into my CSS file which works fine and placed the HTML and that works fine too, but I cannot seem to be able to trigger the JavaScript to work. Can someone please help and point me to a right direction? Thank you.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>$MODULE_NAME$ - $SITE_NAME$</title>
        <?$META_DESCRIPTION$?>
        <?$META_KEYWORDS$?>
        <link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="/_st/my.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://joxongir.ucoz.com/cardgame.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Deal Card" id="deal" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id='drop' class='drop'>Drop Here</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        $GLOBAL_BFOOTER$
</html>
</table>
</body>
```

JsFiddle file:
http://jsfiddle.net/otpspbhs/5/

The page im trying to get it to work is joxongir.ucoz.com/stuff

Edit:
This is the code i have so far that i have changed around

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>$MODULE_NAME$ - $SITE_NAME$</title>
        <?$META_DESCRIPTION$?>
        <?$META_KEYWORDS$?>
        <link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="/_st/my.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Deal Card" id="deal" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id='drop' class='drop'>Drop Here</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        $GLOBAL_BFOOTER$
<script src="http://joxongir.ucoz.com/cardgame.js"></script>
</html>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: You have the embed version. Just click on the share button on the jsfiddle website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script resource:

```
<script src="http://joxongir.ucoz.com/cardgame.js"></script>
```

Must be loaded after the page is fully loaded. You can do this either by using jQuery's page ready handler, or by placing the script tab prior to the closing body tag.

To explain the problem detail, when line 1 of your external JavaScript script runs, the HTML DOM element `id="deal"` does not exist yet because the browser has not parsed thru the HTML yet. Attaching the event using `$('#deal).click(...` does nothing until the element exists.

Secondary issue:

You have not loaded jQuery UI, add this tag to your head to enable the UI functionality:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Ok i placed the js script into the <body> but it still doesnt work

Comment: It needs to be the very last tag in the body.

Comment: So should i put <input type="button" value="Deal Card" id="deal" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id='drop' class='drop'>Drop Here</div> into the js file? I did put it as a last tag but it still doesnt work

Comment: No. Just move the script tag referencing `cardgame.js` from the head to near the end of the file, just before the closing body tag. The JavaScript must execute after the HTML elements are loaded.

Comment: ok so i did it like this 
 <body>
        <input type="button" value="Deal Card" id="deal" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id='drop' class='drop'>Drop Here</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        $GLOBAL_BFOOTER$
<script src="http://joxongir.ucoz.com/cardgame.js"></script>
</html>
</table>
</body>
but it still wont run

Comment: Ummm... I've heard of callback hell, but `<br>` hell? This is a whole new kettle of fish...!

Comment: Let me try this in the debugger, I was looking for the most obvious problems.

Comment: jQuery *draggable* extension is not loaded. Once loaded, this will work.

Comment: should i load that into a js??? Because i tried to load it on a html and it didnt work

Comment: I was able to make this work locally using the two fixes I showed above.

Comment: Sorry didnt see your edit, yes i went ahead and added the extension and did like you said but havent been able to run it and work. At this point i give up. I have posted an edit of the final modifications that i did. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be helpful

```
<div>
  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/otpspbhs/5" target="_blank"> 
      <button id="navLink">Take to Link</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5u3pkyb/)